# OnLoaded vs. Window_Loaded / event handler versus overriding

Tags: event-handling, performance, overriding

What's better:

```
Private Sub Window_Closed(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Closed
    'Do stuff
End Sub
```

---

```
Protected Overrides Sub OnClosed(ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    MyBase.OnClosed(e)
    'Do stuff
End Sub
```

I personally think that the second is better, 1st because it doesn't add a handler, and also because the syntax is more simple.
Especially in C#, where adding handlers is more robust, and there is no 'handles' keyword.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would favour the event handler, because of maintainability:

- You can't forget to call the base class method `MyBase.OnClosed()`.
- You can easily add multiple handlers.

It does not matter one bit, performance-wise. (I only add this because you tagged the question with performance-comparison... but really, this will only matter if you close forms millions of times a second.)

Comment: Even for each his own taste and I think I will keep using the overriding, I marked your post as answer in honor of the helpful info you provided.